# combine navigation up button with drawer navigation hamburger button inside toolbar

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I am struggling in combining both up button to navigate back through my fragments and the overflow menu "hamburger" button that can open up the navigation drawer menu..
any suggestion how to make it work and have the menu icon on the right and the up button on the left like in the following picture
?

[image]

MainActivity.onCreate part:

```
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
            .apply {
                title = null
            }
        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
```

my Toolbar xml :

```
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/toolbarColor"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24" />
```

I tried adding

```
        val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navController = navHostFragment.navController
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration.Builder(R.id.foundLostFragment)
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(
            this,
            navController,
            appBarConfiguration.build()
        )
```

but it just makes the up button act like the hamburger button so it opens the drawer menu and I cannot manage to have both of the icons displayed on the toolbar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have done to fix my issue was creating a second menu for the toolbar itself with 1 menu item and overrided `onOptionsItemSelected()` to apply that when the toolbar item clicked I just open the drawer menu so in that way I have both up button and both menu item that opens my drawer layout menu :)